# What is the accuracy rate of ChatGPT for simple coding questions?

Tags: chatgpt

ChatGPT [was banned from StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) with the following justification:

> Overall, because the average rate of getting correct answers from
> ChatGPT is too low,
>
> ...
>
> The primary problem is that while the answers which ChatGPT produces
> have a high rate of being incorrect, they typically look like they
> might be good and the answers are very easy to produce.

Has there been any research quantifying how accurate ChatGPT is for simple coding questions? Unfortunately the post on StackOverflow's Meta did not provide a source for their claims.

Comment: Complement: [How good ChatGPT is at answering questions?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/45758/2680)